# Turn my stacked bar chart into a 100% stacked bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, bar-chart

I currently have a stacked bar chart for brewers. There are 6 brewers. It is good to understand the volume but I want to highlight in my analysis that some of the brewers are being used more than others. To do so I need to turn my bar chart in to 100% stacked bar.

[What it currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhP62.png)

I want it so that each of these bars y-axis is always 100.

The code I have at the moment is:

```
def brewer_number_bar(location):
    
    brewer_df_filtered = brewer_df[(brewer_df['Location Name'].isin(location))]

    
    traces = []
    for brewer in brewer_df['Menu Item Name'].unique():
        brewer_df_by_brewer = brewer_df_filtered[brewer_df_filtered['Menu Item Name']==brewer]
        traces.append(go.Bar(
            x = brewer_df_by_brewer['Business Date'],
            y = brewer_df_by_brewer['Sales Count'],
            name=brewer,
            ))
        
    return {'data': traces,
            'layout': go.Layout(title='Brewer Volume',
                               xaxis={'title': 'Date', 'categoryorder': 'total descending'},
                               yaxis={'title': 'Brewer Numbers Used'},
                               barmode='stack')
                               }
```

I have tried to take `brewer_df_by_brewer['Sales Count'] / brewer_df_by_brewer['Sales Count'].sum()` and created a new trace for each but as I also have location in there it has not worked.

Head of the dataframe `brewer_df`

```
{'Business Date': {0: Timestamp('2022-09-05 00:00:00'), 1: Timestamp('2022-09-05 00:00:00'), 2: Timestamp('2022-09-05 00:00:00'), 3: Timestamp('2022-09-05 00:00:00'), 4: Timestamp('2022-09-05 00:00:00')}, 'Major Category': {0: 'Brewer Number', 1: 'Brewer Number', 2: 'Brewer Number', 3: 'Brewer Number', 4: 'Brewer Number'}, 'Location Name': {0: 'France', 1: 'France', 2: 'France', 3: 'Germany', 4: 'Germany'}, 'Menu Item Name': {0: '1', 1: '2', 2: '3', 3: '4', 4: '1'}, 'Sales Count': {0: 176, 1: 163, 2: 22, 3: 7, 4: 89}}
```

Comment: can we see a sample of `brewer_df`? you can copy and paste the output from `brewer_df.head().to_dict()` into your question

Comment: I have added the head on the bottom of the question. Thanks in advance. @DerekO

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your function by using plotly.express. This allows you to stack bars by default, pass the category to the x parameter, and also specify which column you want for the color. I've also used a pandas `groupby + transform` operation that divides each unique location and date in your filtered dataframe by its sum – this is a little cleaner and also more performant than looping through `brewer_df['Menu Item Name'].unique()`.

In order to make sure we are taking dates into account, I've extended your sample dataframe to include more than one day:

```
Timestamp = pd.Timestamp
brewer_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Business Date': {
        0: Timestamp('2022-09-05 00:00:00'), 
        1: Timestamp('2022-09-05 00:00:00'), 
        2: Timestamp('2022-09-05 00:00:00'), 
        3: Timestamp('2022-09-05 00:00:00'), 
        4: Timestamp('2022-09-05 00:00:00'),
        5: Timestamp('2022-09-06 00:00:00'), 
        6: Timestamp('2022-09-06 00:00:00'), 
        7: Timestamp('2022-09-06 00:00:00'), 
        8: Timestamp('2022-09-06 00:00:00'), 
        9: Timestamp('2022-09-06 00:00:00')
    }, 
    'Major Category': {
        0: 'Brewer Number', 
        1: 'Brewer Number', 
        2: 'Brewer Number', 
        3: 'Brewer Number', 
        4: 'Brewer Number',
        5: 'Brewer Number', 
        6: 'Brewer Number', 
        7: 'Brewer Number', 
        8: 'Brewer Number', 
        9: 'Brewer Number'
    }, 
    'Location Name':{
        0: 'France', 
        1: 'France', 
        2: 'France', 
        3: 'Germany', 
        4: 'Germany',
        5: 'France', 
        6: 'France', 
        7: 'France', 
        8: 'Germany', 
        9: 'Germany'
    }, 
    'Menu Item Name': {
        0: '1', 
        1: '2', 
        2: '3', 
        3: '4', 
        4: '1',
        5: '2', 
        6: '3', 
        7: '4', 
        8: '1', 
        9: '2'
    }, 
    'Sales Count': {
        0: 176,
        1: 163, 
        2: 22, 
        3: 7, 
        4: 89,
        5: 90,
        6: 6, 
        7: 14, 
        8: 22, 
        9: 200
    }
})
```

Then the modified `brewer_number_bar` callback looks like the following:

```
def brewer_number_bar(location):
    brewer_df_filtered = brewer_df[brewer_df['Location Name'] == location].copy()
    brewer_df_filtered['Sales Count Percent'] = brewer_df_filtered['Sales Count'] / brewer_df_filtered.groupby(['Location Name','Business Date'])['Sales Count'].transform('sum')

    fig = px.bar(brewer_df_filtered, x="Business Date", y="Sales Count Percent", color="Menu Item Name")
    fig.update_layout(
        title='Brewer Volume',
        xaxis={'title': 'Date', 'categoryorder': 'total descending'},
        yaxis={'title': 'Brewer Numbers Used', 'tickformat': ',.0%'},
    )
    return fig
```

Below are two example figs that this callback would return, one when you pass `'France'` as the location with `fig = brewer_number_bar('France')`, and the other when you pass 'Germany' as the location:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Derek, thanks. I wanted the x axis to be Dates, not location. The key would be the menu item name as you have prepared. The location is in an input callback, which is triggered through 'location' when someone say chooses France in the dropdown

Comment: @coffeefin thanks for the feedback! i've updated my answer – hopefully this is what you were looking for